# ¿Como separo esta linea para que solo me de los decimales? Python3

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Quiero que de esa linea que se imprimio solo me muestre los decimales]

Ya hizo la busqueda, ya imprimio las lineas que deben ser, pero ahora quiero que de eso que se imprimio solo me muestre los decimales. Ayudenme UnU

Comment: `print([elem[1] for elem in lista[0:3]])`

Comment: Oh muchas gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
La idea del sitio es poderte ayudar y resolver tus dudas. Para eso, la idea es tener un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) donde veamos los datos de prueba, la salida esperada y poderlo replicar. Así pues, todo va como texto, no como imagen.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Vales mil :D nunca lo habria pensado xd

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: cierra la pregunta